# Determine DRM system supported by browser

Tags: html, html5-video, drm

I've trying to find out how to determine which DRM system browser is using. And in fact, only chrome say it is use 'com.widevine.alpha' where IE & Safari (Win) throw error on 'requestMediaKeySystemAccess', and firefox do not even try to say it use 'com.adobe.acccess' =]

```
 function isKeySystemSupported(keySystem) {

    var dfd = Q.defer();
    console.log('check: ', keySystem);
    navigator.requestMediaKeySystemAccess(keySystem, [{contentType: 'video/webm; codecs="vp9"'}]).then(function() {
        dfd.resolve(true);
    }, function() { dfd.resolve(false); } );

    return dfd.promise;
}
```

is there any solution, like Modernizr or similar to get which keySystem I should use?

Comment: check this article which i wrote recently : http://aameer.github.io/articles/digital-rights-management-multi-drm/  it explains in details about how to achieve multi-drm , check the section about about current status

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are several websites offering such a check, like [dash-player.com/browser-capabilities/](http://www.dash-player.com/browser-capabilities/) After having a closer look at how it is done, one can use something similar to:

```js
// EME Check
var keySystems = {
  widevine: ['com.widevine.alpha'],
  playready: ['com.microsoft.playready', 'com.youtube.playready'],
  clearkey: ['webkit-org.w3.clearkey', 'org.w3.clearkey'],
  primetime: ['com.adobe.primetime', 'com.adobe.access'],
  fairplay: ['com.apple.fairplay']
};
var keySystemsCount = (function () {
  var count = 0;
  for (keysys in keySystems) {
    if (keySystems.hasOwnProperty(keysys)) {
      count += keySystems[keysys].length;
    }
  }
  return count;
})();

var testVideoElement = document.createElement('video');
var supportedSystems = [];
var unsupportedSystems = [];

var supportsEncryptedMediaExtension = function () {
  if (!testVideoElement.mediaKeys) {
    if (window.navigator.requestMediaKeySystemAccess) {
      if (typeof window.navigator.requestMediaKeySystemAccess === 'function') {
        console.log('found default EME');
        hasEME = true;
        var isKeySystemSupported = function (keySystem) {
          var config = [{initDataTypes: ['cenc']}];
          if (window.navigator.requestMediaKeySystemAccess) {
            window.navigator.requestMediaKeySystemAccess(keySystem, config).then(function (keySystemAccess) {
              supportedSystems.push(keySystem);
            }).catch(function () {
              unsupportedSystems.push(keySystem);
            });
          }
        };
        var keysys, dummy, i;
        for (keysys in keySystems) {
          if (keySystems.hasOwnProperty(keysys)) {
            for (dummy in keySystems[keysys]) {
              isKeySystemSupported(keySystems[keysys][dummy]);
            }
          }
        }
      }
    } else if (window.MSMediaKeys) {
      if (typeof window.MSMediaKeys === 'function') {
        console.log('found MS-EME');
        hasEME = true;
        var keysys, dummy, i;
        for (keysys in keySystems) {
          if (keySystems.hasOwnProperty(keysys)) {
            for (dummy in keySystems[keysys]) {
              if (MSMediaKeys.isTypeSupported(keySystems[keysys][dummy])) {
                supportedSystems.push(keySystems[keysys][dummy]);
              } else {
                unsupportedSystems.push(keySystems[keysys][dummy]);
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    } else if (testVideoElement.webkitGenerateKeyRequest) {
      if (typeof testVideoElement.webkitGenerateKeyRequest === 'function') {
        console.log('found WebKit EME');
        hasEME = true;
        var keysys, dummy, i;
        for (keysys in keySystems) {
          if (keySystems.hasOwnProperty(keysys)) {
            for (dummy in keySystems[keysys]) {
              if (testVideoElement.canPlayType('video/mp4', keySystems[keysys][dummy])) {
                supportedSystems.push(keySystems[keysys][dummy]);
              } else {
                unsupportedSystems.push(keySystems[keysys][dummy]);
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    } else {
      console.log('no supported EME implementation found');
      hasEME = false;
    }
  }
}
```

Simply run *supportsEncryptedMediaExtension()* and *supportedSystems* will be filled with the desired information.

Note that the `config` object should be extended to include the specific codec claims respective to your particular media. It isn't enough to just detect the key system as codec support sometimes depends on Guest OS dependencies.

```
var config = [{
     "initDataTypes": ["cenc"],
     "audioCapabilities": [{
          "contentType": "audio/mp4;codecs=\"mp4a.40.2\""
     }],
     "videoCapabilities": [{
          "contentType": "video/mp4;codecs=\"avc1.42E01E\""
     }]
}];
```

Comment: This is great! Where did you find the list of key system strings? I know `org.w3.clearkey` comes from the w3 spec - https://w3c.github.io/encrypted-media/#common-key-systems -. But I have trouble tracking down where the others come from.

Comment: Safari seems to return undefined on the `webkitGenerateKeyRequest` property. Does anyone are experimenting this problem?
Thanks

Answer (score 5):

In addition to the information listed here, I want to mention that in Chrome, whether you are using `https` or not will affect the availability of `navigator.requestMediaKeySystemAccess` function.

In your development environment that probably is running on `http`, `navigator.requestMediaKeySystemAccess` will return `undefined` for **Chrome** whereas the same code will return a function in **Firefox**.

In your prod environment that has `https`, `navigator.requestMediaKeySystemAccess` will return a function **both** in Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: On Firefox, its working with http, but giving warning that soon it will be deprecated and use of https will be mandatory.

Answer (score 5):

I had to give `videoCapabilities` flags to make this work.

```
function testEME() {
  // https://shaka-player-demo.appspot.com/support.html
  var keySysConfig = [{
    "initDataTypes": ["cenc"]
      //,"persistentState": "required"  // don't use or MacSafari "not supported"
      //,"persistentState": "required", "distinctiveIdentifier": "required"
      //,"audioCapabilities": [{
      //  "contentType": "audio/mp4;codecs=\"mp4a.40.2\""
      //}]
      ,"videoCapabilities": [{
    "contentType": "video/mp4;codecs=\"avc1.4D401E\"" // avc1.42E01E = ConstrainedLevel3, 4D401E=MainLevel3
    //,"robustness": "3000"
      }]
  }];           
        
  var keySystems = {
    playready: ['com.microsoft.playready.recommendation', 'com.microsoft.playready'
      , 'com.microsoft.playready.hardware', 'com.youtube.playready'],
    clearkey: ['webkit-org.w3.clearkey', 'org.w3.clearkey'],
    widevine: ['com.widevine.alpha'],
    primetime: ['com.adobe.primetime', 'com.adobe.access'],
    fairplay: ['com.apple.fairplay','com.apple.fps'
      , 'com.apple.fps.1_0', 'com.apple.fps.2_0', 'com.apple.fps.3_0']
  };
            
  for(keyArr in keySystems) {
    for(forItemIdx in keySystems[keyArr]) {
      let keySys = keySystems[keyArr][forItemIdx];
      try {
         navigator.requestMediaKeySystemAccess(keySys, keySysConfig).
         then(function(mediaKeySystemAccess) {
         //let mkConfig = mediaKeySystemAccess.getConfiguration();
         //let sFlags = "persistentState="+mkConfig.persistentState 
         //  + ", distinctiveIdentifier="+mkConfig.distinctiveIdentifier; 
        console.log(keySys + " supported"); //+" ("+sFlags+")");
      }).catch(function(ex) {
         console.log(keySys+" not supported (" + ex.name+" "+ex.message+")." );
      });
      } catch (ex) {
        console.log(keySys+" not supported (" + ex.name+" "+ex.message+").." );
      }
    }
  }
}
```