# Is there any ways to detect screen recorder using js

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make screen black when a screen recorder is on and user is viewing videos in fullscreen. Is it possible with js?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you already read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48710312/way-to-support-drm-system-supported-by-browser-using-javascript)?

Comment: Webpages detecting what processes the user is running, would be a privacy violation, so I am pretty sure the answer is "no".

Comment: there is a team who did this already. thats why thinking its possible

Answer (score -1):

I dont think there is an way do that using javascript till now , but u can disable in built windows screen recorder by adding keyeventlisteners to windows key + g , you can do only this with javascript...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).